# broaden definition to include pros and micros

Tags: discussion, stackexchange2.0

In discussion about merging some other Alcohol related sites it was suggested that rather that trying to merge in Home brewing (which is undoubtedly struggling to get it's **questions per day** up), instead it was suggested that re-branding your site to something more inclusive of *industrial* and *micro* brewers might up your question rate, and bring more expert knowledge to the table.

Just a suggestion from an outsider so feel free to ignore me, good luck with your site,

GBB x

[Alcohol proposal](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/other-alcohol-sites-too-specific-to-make-critical-mass)

Answer (score 4):

As much as I respect commercial brewers, my experience is that what they do is so different than homebrewing that very often they don't understand the differences.  Much of what they do and know has no bearing on homebrewing and vice versa.  I would hate to dilute the knowledge base just to increase the post count.

Comment: As much as I like the idea of trying to up the PPD, I have to agree with Denny Conn. This place is great for new/seasoned homebrewers looking for knowledge that is pertinent to exactly that. ...although I'm also a newbie to this particular site so my opinion may not carry weight either. :shrug:

Comment: I agree, but what about nanos/micros? Don't most small-scale brewers start out as homebrewers?

Comment: I'd say "some" not "most".  And once they hit more than 1/2 bbl. batches, the scale they're at doesn't really relate to homebrewers.